# what is the official version of Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, operating-system, version

A client is asking for the "official" current version of WP7 that apps are being built for. I cannot find any documentation stating the current version, is it simply "Windows Phone 7 version 1.0"?

I guess I just need to know so that when future releases come out we know what version it is "targeted" for.

Comment: bah just found it under settings...

Answer (score 4):

If you go to Settings -> System -> about -> more information you can see that it is **7.0.7004.0**

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [SDK](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started) download page you'll see there is the SDK and then there is the Jan 2011 Update.  I'm sure they have different minor version numbers, but it seems they may be planning on referring to them by dates?

Future releases should be backward compatible...

Answer (score 0):

It's 7.0.7004.0 at the moment but bear in mind that there are 2 updates coming in the next few weeks.

This information can be found at Settings -> About -> More Information on the phone or View Sync Options -> Update on Zune.